# Flatten Either with the same types on the both sides

Tags: scala, identity, flatten, fold, either

Let's suppose, you have something with type `F[Either[T, T]]` and you want to flatten `Either` under your `F` because both of `Either` types have the same type and the value doesn't matter for your program.

I found just using `Either.fold` and use `identity` function twice for both sides but I think there is should be the better way to do this.

```scala
import cats.Functor
import cats.syntax.functor._

import scala.concurrent.Await
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.duration.DurationInt
import scala.language.higherKinds

def foo[F[_]: Functor, T](eitherF: F[Either[T, T]]): F[T] =
  eitherF.map(either => either.fold(identity, identity))

val flattenProcess = foo[Future, String](Future(Left[String, String]("left")))
  .flatMap{
    prev =>
      println(prev)
      foo[Future, String](Future(Right[String, String]("rigth")))
  }
println(Await.result(flattenProcess, 10.seconds))
// prints: 
// left
// rigth
```

here I use `Future` just for example of some wrapped effect.

Does `scala` std lib or maybe `cats` library has something to make it more elegant?
Or maybe it is just a problem of my bad design of using `Either`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [`Either#merge`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/7d7daa6be0f84364111fc217fddc161e2984ff48/src/library/scala/util/Either.scala#L502)

```
eitherF.map(_.merge)
```

which converts `Either[T, T]` to `T`.